# How to express this constraint efficiently?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, integer-programming, indicator-constraints

Let, $\mathcal{C}=\{1,2,\cdots,C\}$,
$\mathcal{U}=\{1,2,\cdots,U\}$

$\mathcal{S}_u$ is a subset of $\mathcal{C}$ with $u\in \mathcal{U}$

$d_{u,c}$ is a binary variable with $u=1,2,\cdots,U$ and $c=1,2,\cdots,C$

Now, with $u=1$, if $d_{1,2}=1$ and $d_{1,5}=1$, then we want to enforce that both $2\in\mathcal{S}_u$ and $5\in\mathcal{S}_1$

Similarly,

with $u=3$, if $d_{3,2}=1$ and $d_{3,7}=1$, then we want to enforce that both $2\in\mathcal{S}_3$ and $7\in\mathcal{S}_3$

What is an efficient way of generalising this constraint for any $u\in \mathcal{U}$?

Comment: Is the set $S_u$ known or a decision variable?

Comment: $\mathcal{S}_u$ is a known set. $d_{u,c}$ is a decision variable. If $d_{u,c}=1$, then $c$ must be in the set $\mathcal{S}_u$. How can I mathematically express this constraint without 'If-Then' constraint. I think I can express this constraint as: $\text{If }d_{u,c}=1, \text{ Then }c\in \mathcal{S}_u$.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a sparse index set of ordered pairs $(u,c)$ for $d_{u,c}$. Explicitly, the set is $\{(u,c):u\in\mathcal{U},c\in S_u\}$. This way, instead of defining variables that must take the value $0$, you just omit them from the problem.

Answer (score 1):

So if $d_{u,c_1} \cdot d_{u,c_2} =1$ then $\{c_1,c_2\}$ part of $S_u$.

$d_{u,c_1} + d_{u,c_2} -1 \le z_{u,c_1,c_2}$
$z_{u,c_1,c_2} \le d_{u,c_1}$
$z_{u,c_1,c_2} \le d_{u,c_2}$
$z_{u,c_1,c_2} \in\ \{0,1\}$

If using set,
$S_u \cup z_{u,c_1,c_2}\cdot\{c_1,c_2\}$